# Weird thing happens with array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm playing around on codepen.io but for some reason my code is not working as expected:

```
var name = ["one",'two','three'];
$('body').append('<p>'+ name[0] + '</p>');
```

That code is appending the letter "o" to the page. When I switch the code to:

```
var person = ["one",'two','three'];
$('body').append('<p>'+ person[0] + '</p>');
```

"one" is appended to the page. Anybody know what's going on?

Here is the example: http://codepen.io/ntibbs/pen/ZbPPBm

Comment: Unfortunately i dont have access to dev tools on this computer to see this for myself. Thanks for finding this for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be in the global scope, so when you declare your `name` variable, you're clashing with the global [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) property.

This property *has* to be a string, so whenever you assign anything to it, it is coerced to a string.

When `["one",'two','three']` is coerced to a string, it first performs an [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), and you end up with `"one,two,three"`, which is assigned to `name`.  `name[0]` gives you the first character of that, `"o"`.

Using the different variable name, `person`, you don't see this issue because you're not fighting the window property.